# Jersey Client Request Takes Too Long To Reach Server

Tags: java, spring, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

In a JavaFx client application, jersey client 2 is used to send request to the server to fetch data. I control both server and client applications.

The time it takes from when client execute `.get()` to when server receive the request is not less than `8seconds`. That is alot of time considering the request has just 2 path variable.

Spring framework is used for a dependency injection, and i have this in configuration file

```
@Bean
public WebTarget webTarget(){
    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    config.register(new JacksonJsonProvider());
    final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
    client.register(new LoggingFilter());
    return client.target(getBaseUri());
}
```

Then anywhere in service layer request to server needs to be made, a `Webtarge` is `Autowired` and additional request specific info is added like path and request variables.

What should i do to make request time(from start of request to server receiving request -- in localhost) minimal?

## Update

When the same request with is made using `Postman`, request-response time is `2secs`.

Comment: Start by isolating where the problem is since you control both server and client side code. You mentioned its 8 seconds from request to response, so start with putting the server side up and use any rest client like postman to do the request. If it takes almost 8 seconds to get a reply, then post your serverside to give us more info.

Comment: 8 secs if not request-response time, it from time of request to server `receiving request`

Comment: Request-Response time with `Postman` is `2secs`

Comment: You should see about the same time when using postman and jersey client. Are you doing anything else that might take some time before sending the request, e.g. another request? Or is it only the first request, and any subsequent request takes 2 seconds? Maybe you could post your client code used as well?

Comment: By the time this is sent, all other requests have responded

Comment: @geneqew: You are right, the problem is not jersey client, sever has some custom authentication that takes time